# How to test existing React Store

Tags: reactjs, testing, redux, jestjs, easy-peasy

I use Redux powered by "easy peasy". I am trying to test existing React Store. Particularly I need to test the thunk

part of store with thunk that I need to test

```
...
        clients: [],

...
    loadClients: thunk(async (actions) => {
        try {
            const result = await get(`${baseUrl}/api/clients`);
            actions.parseClientsResponse(result);
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
            actions.displayErrorMessage(error);
        }
    }),

        parseClientsResponse: action((storeState, clients) => {
            storeState.clients = clients;
        }),
```

Please help me with any ideas how to test it. Assume that the thunk does not take any parameters

Comment: Did https://easy-peasy.dev/docs/tutorials/testing.html#testing-thunks not help? The strategy seems to be the same as with classic thunks btw. You let jest mock all the external functions that your thunk is calling and then assert on the sequence of plain actions that are dispatched.

Comment: Thanks. Actually I have seen that examples. It didn't help me much. Can you provide some examples with jest mocks?

Comment: In your case you need to mock the `get` function from your example that triggers the http request. If `get` is from a library like axios, search for "axios jest mock", there are a ton of examples. You probably want to research how mocking with jest works in general. It's easier to help you if you can provide code where you tried it yourself. Otherwise we're just copy-pasting from existing answer or tutorials here.

Comment: Ok. You are right. But how can I mock the get method in existing thunk?

Comment: That depends on where it's coming from, I can't see where you're importing it.

Comment: `const get = async (url) => {
    const response = await fetch(url, {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: new Headers({
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        }),
    });
    checkRedirect(response);

    if (!response.ok) {
        const error = { ...await response.json() };
        throw error;
    }
    return response.json();
};`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243647/discussion-between-timotgl-and-leotim).

Answer (score 0):

Eventually, since fetch executes my api call behind the scene, I have solved it using fetchMock

```
import fetchMock from "jest-fetch-mock";

fetchMock.enableMocks();

    beforeEach(() => {
        fetch.resetMocks();
    });

fetch.mockResponseOnce(JSON.stringify(responseObject));
```

Thank you @timotgl for help